# Visual Studio does not apply provisioning profile to MAUI iOS app in Debug mode

Tags: ios, .net-core, maui, provisioning-profile

I have a Xamarin Forms app which I upgraded to .NET MAUI. Visual Studio recognizes the provisioning profile (if I open the dropdown I can see two valid ones, a wildcard and a specific one - I have already tried to manually select the right one here, but to no avail):

[image]

and the build output says it's recognized too:

```
Target _DetectSigningIdentity:
    Detected signing identity:
            
      Code Signing Key: "Apple Development: Gerwin de Groot (<some id>)" (<some other id>)
      Provisioning Profile: "Example (Debug)" (<some id>)
      Bundle Id: com.example.test
      App Id: <team id>.com.example.test
```

yet the deployment to the device fails:

```
 CopyingFile - Path: /Users/gerwin/Public/Projects/Example/bin/Debug/net6.0-ios/ios-arm64/Example.app/Poppins-MediumItalic.ttf
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 99%
 CreatingStagingDirectory - PercentComplete: 5%
 ExtractingPackage - PercentComplete: 15%
 InspectingPackage - PercentComplete: 20%
 PreflightingApplication - PercentComplete: 30%
 VerifyingApplication - PercentComplete: 40%
 ApplicationVerificationFailed: Failed to verify code signature of /var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.0vKSvJ/extracted/Example.app : 0xe8008015 (A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.)
error MT1006: Could not install the application '/Users/gerwin/Public/Projects/Example/bin/Debug/net6.0-ios/ios-arm64/Example.app' on the device 'Gerwin's iPhone 11': AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle returned: 0xe8008015.


Application could not be uploaded to the device.
```

It's visible on the iPhone, but with a blank application icon and a cloud indicator:

[image]

and tapping it gives an error message

> #### Unable To Install "Example"
>
> This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified.

I get similar results if I try to use the command line, e.g. with

```
dotnet build Example.csproj -c Debug -f net6.0-ios -t:Run -p:_DeviceName=<device UDID>
```

though surprisingly, Release mode (`-c Release` instead of `-c Debug`) works (from the Command line, not from Visual Studio itself because of [another bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Building-in-Release-mode-for-iOS-results/10235007)).

How can I fix this?

Comment: I have the similar issue trying to run on Ipad.
All profiles allow the Ipad as testing device.
None of the three answers works for me..
Could not find the application 'com.company.myapp' on the device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying to deploy Microsoft's template app (that worked) and gradually adding features from the original app (a very painful process ...) I managed to find the problem: the entitlements. It looked like this (and that's how it should be for Release/Distribution builds):

[image]

but Debug builds should use the `development` APS environment. Apparently, that is not checked during compile/build time, only upon installation.

Answer (score 3):

This is gonna be long.

First, I had to enter my IOS account, being part of the team with admin (not sure if any lower will work) privileges.

This is done in tools > settings > xamarin > AppleAccounts. If you do not do it when the popup appears.

In the Project Properties, I had to select Automatic Provisioning and follow the steps.

Theoretically it should have:

1. Add certificate.
2. Add identifier.
3. Add the device.
4. Add profile.

However, it failed at step 2.
So I had to go to:
https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list

And add the identifier myself. If your app is com.mycompany.myapp, create it like: com.mycompany.*.

After that, I returned to the project properties, and tried the automatic provisioning again.

It detected, that step 1 and 2 were done, added the device, added the profile, signed and deployed it successfully.

(Keep in mind that debugging using hot reload does not handle app icon, splash screen, etc... so do not get surprised when you find them missing.)

Every now and then I have to do this procedure again, because when I update the VS or the .NET version, unexplained problems happen.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know automatic signing was possible, but I've activated that now. I can see in the Apple Developer Portal that Visual Studio (for Mac in my case) created a provisioning profile, but unfortunately still the same error :(

Comment: @Glorfindel you have developer certificate, identifier with wildcard that matches com.mycompany.*, application that is com.mycompany.myapp, developer device in the list, and Wildcard development profile that is marked as IOS development? All those, exactly like that?

Comment: More or less - I have both `com.mycompany.*` and `com.mycompany.myapp` identifiers, I have a development profile (generated by Xcode) valid for identifier `*`, and I'll need a specific one for the app anyway (because it uses push notifications) and Visual Studio generated it for me. It just doesn't use it while signing ...

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your iOS device are not trusted.

There are several ways to provision the iOS device,

1. [Manual provisioning for iOS apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=vs). When generating a new provisioning file, remember to also include the device you want to deploy. Actually i prefer using this way as it's more clear to me.
2. [Automatic provisioning for iOS apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=vs).

You could check the document above and have a try.

Hope it works for you.