# .NET MAUI Valid Provisioning Profile Issue

Tags: maui

Using Visual Studio 17.4.4 on Windows 11 and I’m unable to test my .NET MAUI app on a tethered iPhone Xs because I get the following error in Xamarin logs.

> A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found

I tried it both with manual provisioning as well as automatic provisioning to no avail. I also have the `Entitlements.plist` file under `\Platforms\iOS` folder.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to fix this issue?

Comment: Provisioning profiles are saved on Windows under %LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\iOS\Provisioning\Profiles. If not there, you could copy it to the folder.

Comment: This is how I solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75005166/6643940. I do not know if it will work for you.

Comment: I manually downloaded the provisioning profile and placed in the folder as @LiqunShen-MSFT suggested. I also followed H.A.H.'s instructions and still not working. Funny thing is when I first start the debug process, I see that it finds both the cert and the provisioning profile. Only when it comes to deploying to device stage, it stops with an error "The app 'MyApp.app' could not be deployed to the device 'iPhone'. Please check the logs for more details. You can open Xamarin logs from the Help menu." and in the logs it indicates the issue w/ provisioning profile I mentioned in original post.

Comment: I found a similar issue : [A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/:-0xe8008015-A-valid-provisioning-profi/10073337?space=8&q=hotrestart&sort=newest). There's a workaround by modifying entitlement.plist.

Comment: Nothing I tried worked so I created a new MAUI app and gave it the same bundle ID. Basically, a standard blank MAUI app with BundleId of my original app. I then connect my iPhone via USB to make sure I can deploy this new app to my phone and it works! I then copy and paste all the files from original project, including csproj file. It still works fine and I can deploy my app to my iPhone and debug it w/o any issues. This works for about an hour. Then all of a sudden, it stops working! Every time I start debugging, I get the original error! Can anyone make any sense out of this?

Comment: You could report a problem to Visual Studio. In Visual Studio, click   **_Help_** -> **_Send_** **_a_** **_Feedback_** -> **_Report a Problem_** .

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT Already did

Comment: I saw it. We could also follow this thread: [MAUI: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MAUI:-A-valid-provisioning-profile-for-t/10261464?sort=newest&stateGroup=active&ftype=problem&q=Provisioning&ref=native&refTime=1675234291307&refUserId=122037f4-e256-6057-aef4-09cded8a37e7) Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this question a long time after it was asked if only to remind myself when it happens to me again, because Microsoft *still* doesn't believe this is happening.

Try emptying out your Entitlements.plist file down to ONLY an empty `<dict></dict>` element (plus the header boilerplate).

It seems this somehow fixes provisioning temporarily for me. To extend the temporariness I have made an entitlement file for each build configuration, with the debug one being empty as described above and the prod one having the stuff I actually need for prod (luckily for me it's just beta-reports-active and I don't need anything for debug builds).