# My .net maui app using Hot Restart pn iOS device fails building with: Invalid request. Service mapping the the requested url is not available

Tags: ios, maui

I am trying to run the debug version of our .net maui app on a local iOS device (iPad), but Visual Studio 2022 x64 (17.5.1) keeps saying:
There was an error while trying to automatically provision the project:
"Invalid request. Service mapping the the requested url is not available."
during hot restart setup.
I have no idea of what service mapping or URL it is referring to.
I am running VS on Windows 11 connected to a Mac Mini with xcode. Using the simulator works.
Testing our app on a physical device is a must.

I should have fixed the certificates and downloaded the provisioning profile in VS.
Also running the dotnet cli trying the make a release, it will say it created an ipa package in  bin\Release\net7.0-ios\ios-arm64\publish
but there is nothing there

Comment: This is how I solved my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75005166/6643940 You need to see where exactly your automatic provisioning fails. There are certain steps that are being taken.

Comment: Did you follow the steps in the Maui documentation ([Deploy an iOS app using hot restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/hot-restart?view=net-maui-7.0))?

Comment: I did add certificates and eneabled hot restart or I wouldn't have reached this point.
The error is from the last step of Setup Hot Restart

Comment: You can try and double check the following steps:
1. Clean the solution and delete the bin/obj file
2. Open VS, go to Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Apple Account, add your apple id (if you are already logged in, delete it and add it again)
3.go to iOS Bundle Signing, click select a team , then select your team again, it will update the VS: WildCard Development profile.

Comment: Well it still does the same shit (after choosing the team it fails with Invalid request, Service mapping to the requested URL is not available). It makes me wonder what URL it refers to as I have not setup any URL to any service. Is that URL in the provisioning profile? because I keep downloading them from the apple account...

Comment: Confirm that the Bundle Identifier in your app's configuration file matches your app's Bundle Identifier in the Developer Center.

Comment: We had a consultant fix this issue. I am not exactly sure what he did on our mac, but we can now build a debug version for a device (iPad) that works or a release version (IPA) that would crash instantly when running it from testflight.